# VSTO Outlook: subscribing ItemAdd event for all the folders in the heriarchy makes saved draft shown incorrectly in the draft folder list

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have an Outlook Add-in in which I need to subscribe to ItemAdd event for all the folders in the heriarchy in order to monitor and do some stuff. After subscribing to it I have observed that the default Outlook behavior for folders on ItemAdd is missed, for example, in particular the draft folder, I mean, I write a new email from compose window and then I do not send it, I simply close compose window so Outlook asks me if I want to save changes and I click on yes button but the problem is that the email saved into the draft folder does not show the date, date of the draft appears as "None". So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does an empty event handler brings the same results? What is your code? How can I reproduce the issue on my side?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Also i have observed that if I subscribe to ItemAdd event for Outbox folder, then if i try to send a new message, the message is not sent nor stored in the sent ítems folder instead it is stored in the Outbox folder even if in the AddItem event i don't do anything in case of Outbox folder. Why?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Regarding my previous comment about the Outbox issue, i have exactly the same problem as explained here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/69ac2947-cf12-42cf-80a4-61a4f78d5ebe/mails-getting-deposited-to-outbox-folder-only-if-i-handle-outbox-folders-itemadd-event?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Don't touch items in the Outbox folder. Instead, you may handle the `ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, I don't want to touch ítems in the Outbox folder. I need to handle when an item is manually moved from one folder to another. So i subscribe to itemadd and beforeitemmoved folder events for all folders of the root folder tree. Outlook offers to the user the possibility to move ítems into Outbox so I need to monitor it. What happens is that when sending a new email, the itemadd event is raised for Outbox, i don't know why.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with an empty event handler for the Outbox folder?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev If I put a breakpoint in the Items_ItemAdd folder when it is raised for the Outbox folder and then I do not execute any code within the event (the same as it was empty), then the mail is sent correctly so can I assume that the problem is due to the code within the Items_ItemAdd event?

Comment: Yes, the problem can't be related to an empty event handler. Just don't touch the item in the Outbox folder - let the MAPI spooler do its job.

Answer (score 0):

An empty `ItemAdd` event handler is not related to the issue. Only your could cause issues. To give a more precise answer you need to publish your code.